# Sending raw data over a tcp socket with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a domotica system, and I've recovered by using Wireshark the commands, but I can't get them send properly.

This is what I've got:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket


TCP_IP = '10.20.0.195'
TCP_PORT = 9761
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
MESSAGE1 = b"02:63:82:00:06"
MESSAGE2 = b"02:63:82:80:06" 

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.send(MESSAGE1)
s.send(MESSAGE2)
s.close()
```

If I look in Wireshark, I see packages with no data attached. How can I fix this?

I'm using Python 3.

Comment: Looks like it works for me. Can you paste your TCPDump output? I did "tcpdump -X -ni lo tcp port 9761". When you say "packages" do you mean "packets"?

Comment: i've got it working by encoding the message's with binascii.unhexlify(SMESSAGE1)